# How to get ids of facebook invited friends by user in my asp.net4.0 web application

Tags: facebook, asp.net-4.0

I am developing an ASP.NET application. I implemented Facebook JavaScript API in my application, for connect with Facebook and get FB friend list of user. I had done this successfully.
Now, I want to count how many friends are invited by user. Is it possible with facebook API. User can select multiple friends and i want to count how many friends selected and invited by user, Invited friends Id is bonus if We can get.
Please don't forget that facebook changed its Oauth settings for security reasons.
I'm also trying to get ids values after Send Invitation button clicked and page post back to

```
if (Request.Form["ids"] != null)
        {
            span1.InnerHtml = "ids";
//put success code here..
        }
        else
        {
            span1.InnerHtml = "oops no id";
        }
      if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
span1.InnerHtml = "ids";
//put success code here..
}
else
{
span1.InnerHtml = "oops no id";
}
```

but in this case program control always goes to else condition it means after page is post back form return null value.
Is there any way to get ids of invited friends.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Facebook Requests to send invites (you really should, it's intended for this), the only way to get invited friends is via Facebook [`Requests Dialog`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) callback:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'Whoa!'}, callback);

function callback(response){
  // response.to now contain array of invited users ids
  console.log('Invited friends ids', response.to);
  if (response.request) {
    console.log('Efficient Request id', response.request);
  } else {
    console.log('Requests Ids', response.request_ids);
  }
}
```

There is no way to get request sent by user via Graph API or FQL, you only can get requests received by user. You may save all requests sent by your users and rely on this data if you need aggregated count of invitation sent...

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I resolve this issue and get invited friends ids.. 
As we know we use javascript sdk for FB connect so my solution is in concern of Java script:

Just make on change in your .js file where you put your facebook connect javascript code. Use Get or Request Method instead of Post Method in fb:request-form tag.
`<script type="text/javascript>
    var fbhtml = "<fb:serverFbml width=\"" + width_of_invitation_div + "\">
    <script type=\"text/fbml\"><fb:fbml><fb:request-form action=" + window.location + " method="REQUEST" invite="true" type="" + type_of_fb_request_form + "" hold=" /><br mode="></fb:request-form></fb:fbml></script></fb:serverfbml>"
</script>`

After invitation send to users selected friends you get ids[] in url.
you can get these ids through query string and split ids by comma(,) and store in array.
Hope this will help for other devs.

Comment: What you have here is FBML which is in phase of deprecation by Facebook. Cite from notice on top of [FBML reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/): «On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed.»

Comment: Thanks for your attention, You are right but now what is new way to get friends id in my asp.net web app. Please suggest me new idea to get this whole process.

Comment: Thank you very much. But i checked my app and I am not able to send request from my site. what actually happened is, users are able to login and get friend list of FB friend and select their friends. Once they select friends and try  to send invitation, nothing is happen. "Loding.." text appear for few seconds and then user stay on that page. My website user can't send invitation to FB friends.